# change the font size in tag cloud

Tags: wordpress, tag-cloud

I would like to reduce the font size in tag cloud (at least for tags with more than one hits). I was looking in css file, but couldn't find anything about font size in tag cloud. Do you know where to change? (The link is www.veda-vit.de, just in case it's needed.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

WordPress defines the default arguments that configure the Tag Cloud.  These arguments are defined [here in codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_tag_cloud#Default_Usage).  Notice that you can specify the smallest and largest font size.  By default, it's set at 22 with a unit of `pt`.

To change this default behavior, you will want to register a callback to the filter provided in WordPress Core.

### Code

In this example, I'm changing both the smallest and largest font sizes.  You will need to adjust it for your specific implementation:

```
add_filter( 'widget_tag_cloud_args', 'change_tag_cloud_font_sizes');
/**
 * Change the Tag Cloud's Font Sizes.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 *
 * @param array $args
 *
 * @return array
 */
function change_tag_cloud_font_sizes( array $args ) {
    $args['smallest'] = '10';
    $args['largest'] = '18';

    return $args;
}
```

### Where to Put the Code

A lot of people will tell you to add it to the theme's `functions.php` file. I'm not one of those people.  I teach and advocate [modular](https://knowthecode.io/labs/part-1-introduction-modularity-developers-genesis-starter-child-theme/episode-2) theme and plugin development.  That means the theme's `functions.php` file should not be a collection point for everything.

#### Theme's `functions.php`

With that said, you could add the above code to your `functions.php` file if you wish.

Do the following steps:

1. Open your theme's `functions.php` file.
2. Scroll down to the very bottom of the file.
3. If you find a closing PHP tag element, i.e. `?>`, delete it.  It's not necessary.
4. Copy and paste the above code into the file (at the bottom of the file).
5. Save the file.
6. If it's on a server, then transfer it either by SSH or SFTP.

#### Modular Approach

I advocate a [modular approach](https://knowthecode.io/labs/part-1-introduction-modularity-developers-genesis-starter-child-theme/episode-2), by splitting up functionality and theme configuration into separate, distinct files that support a single purpose.

Step 1: Find the Folder

In your theme, you should a folder called `lib`, `includes`, or `src`.  This folder is where you put custom functionality files.

Step 2: Create a New File

Within one of those folders, create a new file and call it `widgets.php`.  Within this file, add the following code at the first line:

```
<?php
/**
 * Widgets functionality
 *
 * @package     YourTheme
 * @since       1.0.0
 * @author      your name
 * @link        your URL
 * @license     GPL-2+
 */
```

Then add the above code below it.

Step 3: Load the File

Now you need to load that file. Open up the theme's `functions.php` file, navigate to the end of the file, and then add the following code:

```
include_once( __DIR__ . '/lib/widgets.php' );
```

Just replace the `lib` with the name of the folder you put the new file into.

### NOTE

The font-size is set as an inline CSS by WordPress.  You can override those using the above code.  It's not recommended to force it via CSS with `!important`.  Let WordPress do its thing and just set the min and max as shown above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Honestly, I don't understand that much. (Sorry, I am neophyte.) Where do I have to add or change the above code?

Comment: @pradhana I revised my answer to include where to put the code.  I gave you two options.  You can pick what works best for you.

Comment: Great!!! :) Thank you so, so much, hellofromTonya. All the best for you. Greetings, pradhana.

Answer (score 2):

As we don't know how you implement your tag cloud, css is not the only way you have to customize it. the wp_tag_cloud() function accept an array of argument

```
<?php $args = array(
    'smallest'                  => 8, 
    'largest'                   => 22,
    'unit'                      => 'pt', 
    'number'                    => 45,  
    'format'                    => 'flat',
    'separator'                 => "\n",
    'orderby'                   => 'name', 
    'order'                     => 'ASC',
    'exclude'                   => null, 
    'include'                   => null, 
    'topic_count_text_callback' => default_topic_count_text,
    'link'                      => 'view', 
    'taxonomy'                  => 'post_tag', 
    'echo'                      => true,
    'child_of'                  => null, // see Note!
); ?>
```

If you want to modify the default behazviour without touching any template file, you can use the filter `wp_tag_cloud`, in functions.php,

```
add_filter('wp_tag_cloud', 'se_40811909', 10, 2);

function se_40811909($return, $args){

  // copy and modify $args to fit your needs

 // $args = array(.....);

 return $args;

}
```

You can see all details about them [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_tag_cloud)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Benoti. I fixed the problem. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Adding code to the functions.php file, and also trying to add code to set the min and max font-size for the widget tags did no work for me. I  am assuming that the fix given above might have worked before, but not now with the latest releases of WordPress.

My solution was straightforward as most themes allow custom CSS to be added (eg. under the Appearance / Customize menu.

Examine the html that is being used; for example by right-clicking on one of the tags and inspect it using Google inspector. Get the class that has been used for the tags.

In my case this resulted in me adding the following custom CSS:

```
.tag-cloud-link {
  font-size: 14px !important;
  margin-left:1rem;
  margin-right:1rem;
}
```

Adjust the min and max as you need, you can use rem or px for the sizes.

After saving the changes, refresh the page and it should have taken affect.