# Change the font-size in Tag clouds

Tags: wordpress

I want a different font-size in wp tags clouds but it doesn't work.

Template:

```
<div id="tag-clouds">
<?php wp_tag_cloud();?>
</div>
```

Function.php:

```
function tag_cloud_widget_parameters() {
    $args = array(
        'smallest' => 12,
        'largest' => 18,
        'unit' => 'pt',
        'number' => 10,
        'format' => 'flat',
        'separator' => "\n",
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'exclude' => '',
        'include' => '',
        'link' => 'view',
        'taxonomy' => $current_taxonomy,
        'post_type' => '',
        'echo' => false
    );
    return $args;
}


add_filter( 'widget_tag_cloud_args', 'tag_cloud_widget_parameters' );
```

Results:

```
<a href="http://localhost/instal-dev/tag/ds/" class="tag-cloud-link tag-link-20 tag-link-position-8" style="font-size: 8pt;" aria-label="ds (1 pozycja)">ds</a>
<a href="http://localhost/instal-dev/tag/f/" class="tag-cloud-link tag-link-21 tag-link-position-9" style="font-size: 8pt;" aria-label="f (1 pozycja)">f</a>
(...)
```

And all tags have 8pt font-size.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [change the font size in tag cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40811909/change-the-font-size-in-tag-cloud)

Comment: 'pt' is for print, not the web.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code at the end of your theme's function.php

```
add_filter( 'widget_tag_cloud_args', 'change_tag_cloud_font_sizes');
/**
* Change the Tag Cloud's Font Sizes.
*
* @since 1.0.0
*
* @param array $args
*
* @return array
*/
function change_tag_cloud_font_sizes( array $args ) {
$args['smallest'] = '12';
$args['largest'] = '18';

return $args;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code provided is for the widget only. With the function itself you can just add the parameters as an array...

```
<div id="tag-clouds">
<?php
 $args = array(
    'smallest' => 12,
    'largest' => 18,
    'unit' => 'pt',
    'number' => 10,
    'format' => 'flat',
    'separator' => "\n",
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'exclude' => '',
    'include' => '',
    'link' => 'view',
    'taxonomy' => $current_taxonomy,
    'post_type' => '',
    'echo' => false
  );
  wp_tag_cloud($args);
?>
</div>
```

You might have to get the current taxonomy first from some global variable.

See also https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_tag_cloud/